# Why is it possible to access private variables from outside class by reference?

Tags: php, oop

If I have a public class method that is returning a reference to a non-visible (private or protected) property, I can use that reference to gain direct access:

**PHP code**

```
class A
{
    private $property = 'orange';

    public function &ExposeProperty()
    {
        return $this->property;
    }

    public function Output()
    {
        echo $this->property;
    }
}

$obj = new A();

# prints 'orange'
$obj->Output();

$var = &$obj->ExposeProperty();
$var = 'apple';

# prints 'apple'
$obj->Output();
```

Is there a reasoning behind this functionality in PHP? Or is it just a design oversight, failing to keep track of access violations through references?

It obviously comes in handy when you want to achieve something like:

**PHP code**

```
$this->load->resource();
```

Where `load` is an object that modifies given properties of `$this`. But apart from this shortcut, I don't see many possible uses which wouldn't be possible with valid OOP patterns otherwise.

Comment: If you are using references (even worse like that) you deserve what you got :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you *are* explicitly returning a reference to a value. You're locking the front door, but are then opening a side entrance. You *are* very deliberately taking aim and shooting your own foot here. If `$property` was an object, and you'd return this object with or without `&` reference, any modifications to this object would be reflected on `$property` as well. That's how a *reference* works, it always modifies the one and only existing value that the reference points to.

Visibility modifiers aren't magic iron clad "protections". There are any number of ways how you can circumvent a `private` visibility to access and modify the property. They're mostly there as a flag to yourself and other developers that *this property should not be accessed directly, it's for internal use and not a publicly sanctioned API.* And PHP will slap you on the wrist should you forget that. Nothing more, nothing less.

Also, nothing is really being violated here. Outside code is at no point accessing or modifying `$obj->property`. That's the only thing `private` is supposed to prohibit. You're essentially exposing a public API on your object which modifies a `private` property. Usually this is done with getter and setter functions, but a by-reference API obviously works as well.